# Как найти любое расстояние (от А до B) на рисунке по определенной траектории?

Tags: графы

Есть так называемая "карта небольшого городка" в формате JPG. Все дороги обозначены желтым цветом. Как найти кратчайшее расстояние между двумя точками, если точки находятся на желтом цвете? (мне подсказали про теорию графов или что-то такое...я сам технолог, не очень понял про "что") Очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи знатоки)

Comment: вначале нужно будет карту "векторизировать". Это можно сделать как ручками, так и поискать автоматизированные системы (хотя после них придется доделывать). Потом искать/писать софт.

Comment: я думаю большая проблема будет в переводе с jpg формата :)

а по теме, **граф** - это представление всех точек и дорог их соединяющих. **Теория графов** - это различные алгоритмы для нахождения пути от одной точки графа до другой, как минимального, так и любых других.

Answer (score 3):

[Граф](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) - это множество вершин и рёбер, соединяющих эти вершины. Рёбрам могут быть присвоены веса (грубо говоря, их длина). Самая простая аналогия к графу в реальном мире - сеть дорог между городами (или любыми точками).

[image]

Как сказал KoVadim, для начала придётся векторизировать карту, то есть представить все дороги рёбрами, все перекрёстки - вершинами. На полученном графе можно осуществлять поиск пути. Для этого служат алгоритмы вроде A* ([A star](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_A*), поиск в ширину).

Есть ещё один вариант, без векторизации. Если предположить, что все дороги обозначены одинаковым жёлтым цветом, то можно запустить A* непосредственно на растровой карте, передвигаясь только по жёлтым пикселям. Работать это будет **значительно** дольше, и я бы рекомендовал использовать такой вариант только в крайнем случае, если векторизация выльется в очень большие затраты времени и труда.

Comment: >>  Если предположить, что все дороги обозначены одинаковым жёлтым цветом, то можно запустить A* непосредственно на растровой карте, передвигаясь только по жёлтым пикселям.

а потом выяснится, что на карте есть много мест, где желтый не совсем желтый, а где то, что желтое - не дорога. А местами разрывы... А потом ещё выяснится, что некоторые дороги - односторонние. И тут наступит коллапс.

Comment: В принципе, согласен, но...

> а потом выяснится, что на карте есть много мест, где желтый не совсем желтый

С этим можно бороться введя допустимую погрешность по цвету.

>  а где то, что желтое - не дорога

Даже если на карте будут области, по цвету схожие с дорогой, вряд ли они будут с дорогой пересекаться

> А местами разрывы

Это уже зависит от качества карты. Если это скан с сильно потёртой карты, то тут даже автоматическая векторизация не поможет, придётся подправлять граф вручную.

И ещё раз: это плохой путь не по названным вами причинам, а по причине его жуткой неоптимальности.

Comment: >> Даже если на карте будут области, по цвету схожие с дорогой, вряд ли они будут с дорогой пересекаться

о законах Мерфи слышали?:)

Comment: О картографии слышали? ;) На любой нормальной карте изображение должно быть однозначным. Дороги обозначаются контрастным цветом, отличающимся от цветов ландшафта (там обычно выбирают пастельные тона). Впрочем, закон Мерфи вышесказанное не отменяет...

Comment: Я о картографии знаю. Но мы не видели карты вопрошающего. Никто не гарантировал, что она нарисована по правилам. И никто не гарантировал, что и нормальный человек, который видит ту карту в первый раз, сможет однозначно разобраться.

Comment: Ну, значит всю карту нужно для начала нормализовать. Я бы руками подправил ее, сделал бы однозначную маску дорог.

А то с пессимизмом @KoVadim вопрос рассматривается как «карту тибетского путешественника XVII в. н. э. преобразовать в граф» :)

Comment: Думаю векторизировать на порядок быстрее, чем вначале нормализировать, потом пытаться автоматически векторизировать, а потом векторизировать ручками:)

А пессимизма у меня нет. Это здравый реализм.

Comment: Ну почему же, для нормализации может хватить смазывания, а потом чрезмерной фокусировки. Автоматизация — наше все! Даже если для этого нужно долго подготавливать объект :)